# What is the `Telephony.Sms.TYPE` equivalent in `Telephony.Mms`?

Tags: android, sms, mms

I want to pull all the **MMS** messages and tell for each one if it was sent by the user or by the recipient?

In **SMS** it can be done using the [Telephony.Sms.TYPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms) column(message from recipients will be `Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX` and the user is everything else), but how to do it in [Telephony.Mms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms)?
My current solution is to query [Inbox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms.Inbox) and [Outbox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms.Outbox) separately and then combine them. But it's far from ideal.

I also have been trying to use `DATE_SENT`, but it's not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in that way:

```
context.contentResolver.query(
        Telephony.Mms.CONTENT_URI, arrayOf(
            "_id",
            "thread_id",
            "date",
            "m_type",
            "read",
        ), null, null, null
    )
```

and

```
override val viewType: MessageType = when (type) {
    128 -> MessageType.OUTGOING
    else -> MessageType.INCOMING
}
```

I'm not sure it's best solution but it works. IMHO documentation is a little bit confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of SMS `(Telephony.Sms.TYPE)`

In MMS is `(Telephony.Mms.MESSAGE_BOX)`, here the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms

Where `Telephony.Mms.MESSAGE_BOX_INBOX` are those received and everything else is sent by you.